# Emacs auto-complete ESS with julia: working in buffer but not in script

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, julia, ess

I have ESS installed on emacs for use with julia. I also have the auto-complete package installed for completions. Auto-completions work in the julia console buffer but not in .jl julia scripts. I do not have this problem with other languages.

I have the following settings in my init.el:

```
(setq ess-use-auto-complete t)
(setq ess-tab-complete-in-script t)
```

Thank you.

Edit: I should also mention that auto-complete works with R when using ESS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [issue](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/301) was filed for this. You can work around it using [`company-mode`](http://company-mode.github.io/)